# Awk - how to print the number?

Tags: awk

I have a test file:

```
0000 850 1300    Pump  4112 893 2400    Installing sleeve  5910 890 2202    Installing tool 
Testing crankcase and  Protecting oil seal  Installing crankshaft 
carburetor for leaks  (starter side)  5910 890 2208    Installing tool, 8 
0000 855 8106    Sealing plate  4112 893 2401    Press sleeve  Installing hookless 
Sealing exhaust port  Installing oil seal  snap rings in piston 
0000 855 9200    Nipple  (clutch side)  5910 890 2301    Screwdriver, T20 
Testing carburetor for         4118 890 6400    Setting gauge  Separating handle 
leaks  Setting air gap  moldings 
0000 890 1701    Testing tool kit  between ignition  5910 890 2400    Screwdriver, T27x150 
0000 893 2600    Clamping strap  module and flywheel  For all IS screw
```

I want to print only:

```
0000 850 1300
4112 893 2400
5910 890 2202
5910 890 2208
0000 855 8106
.
.
.
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

The numbers in the file are in different places. The numbers are randomly placed in the input file. Each number is the format:

```
xxxx xxx xxxx
```

**EDIT-1:**

I tried two ways, but it does not work on mawk:

```
pic@pic:~/Pulpit$ mawk --traditional -f script.awk infile
mawk: not an option: --traditional
pic@pic:~/Pulpit$ mawk -f script.awk infile
pic@pic:~/Pulpit$
```

Comment: I tried this: `awk '{gsub(/[A-z\/(),;-.]/, ""); print}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shorter and looks for the specific pattern:

```
mawk '
    BEGIN {
        d = "[0-9]"
    }; 
    {
        offset = 1; 
        while (RSTART + RLENGTH < length($0)) {
            if (! match(substr($0, offset), d d d d " " d d d " " d d d d)) {
                next
            }; 
            print substr($0, RSTART+offset - 1, RLENGTH); 
            offset = RSTART + RLENGTH + offset
        }
    }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with `grep` (if your version supports the `-P` flag):

```
grep -oP "[0-9]{4} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}" file.txt
```

Output:

```
0000 850 1300
4112 893 2400
5910 890 2202
5910 890 2208
0000 855 8106
4112 893 2401
0000 855 9200
5910 890 2301
4118 890 6400
0000 890 1701
5910 890 2400
0000 893 2600
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for proposals for a solution, but I want to do it in awk.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`:

Assuming `infile` has the content provided in your question:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
{
    ## Traverse all words of the line but last two. I assume to print three 
    ## consecutive number fields.
    i = 1 
    while ( i <= NF - 3 ) { 

        ## Set current word position in line.
        j = i 

        ## Get next word while current one is a digit, and save it to print later.
        while ( $j ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ ) { 
            value[j] = $j
            ++j 
        }   

        ## If found three consecutive number fields, print them and update counter of
        ## words in the line.
        if ( i + 3 == j ) { 
            for ( key in value ) { 
                printf "%s ", value[key]
            }   
            printf ORS 
            i += 3
        }   
        else {
            ## Failed the search, go to next field and try again.
            ++i 
        }   

        ## Delete array where I save numbers.
        # delete value           <--- Commented for compatibility with older versions.
        for ( key in value ) { 
            delete value[key]
        }
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

With following output:

```
0000 850 1300 
4112 893 2400 
5910 890 2202 
5910 890 2208 
0000 855 8106 
4112 893 2401 
0000 855 9200 
5910 890 2301 
4118 890 6400 
0000 890 1701 
5910 890 2400 
0000 893 2600
```

Comment: Thanks for proposals for a solution.
Your solution works to gawk, but it does not work on mawk. example: `$ mawk -f script.awk infile
pic@pic:~/Pulpit$`

Comment: @Tedee12345: I tried to run it again with `--traditional` switch and gave this error: `awk: script.awk:31: error: 'delete array' is a gawk extension`, so I've edited the answer. Does it work now?

Comment: @Tedee12345: `--traditional` is an option of `gawk` to work as the old `awk`, not an option for `mawk`. I can't access to `mawk` to test this script so can't help with it. Perhaps `[[:digit::]]` is not valid and `[0-9]` is needed instead but it's a shot in the dark. You can also try to debug it adding `print` commands to see where it fails.

Comment: There is no problem. Well, it works with gawk. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Delete array in non-gawk: `split("", value)` (no loop)